# Processing JSON using Pig 0.11.1, source data has carriage returns between JSON objects

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have some source data with multiple JSON objects in a single file.  There are no carriage returns between the objects, if I manually add carriage returns then the Pig 0.11.1 JSONLoader will load each object separately and I get expected Tuples in Pig.  With no carriage returns it will only load the first JSON object in the file.

Is there a way to use the JSONLoader directly to load each object in the file without preprocessing?

If that is not possible any recommendations to easily preprocess the files to add the carriage returns (ideally using Pig)?

Here is an example of the JSON in a file:

`{"values":{"x":447100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"}
 {"values" {"x":454663,"y":154},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"}
 {"values":{"x":455100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"}
 {"values":{"x":456100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"}
 {"values":{"x":457100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"}`

My source data is in an S3 bucket and I am running my Pig jobs using ElasticMapReduce.

Current pig script:

```
a = load '$INPUT' using JsonLoader('values:(x:long,y:int),sbsid:chararray');
b = foreach a generate values.x, values.y, sbsid;
c = filter b by $1 > 0;
d = distinct c;
e = order d by $0 asc;
store d into '$OUTPUT' using PigStorage('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON isn't properly formatted; it needs to be formatted as an array (notice the beginning square brackets and the commas separating key:value "dictionaries":

```
[
    {"values":{"x":447100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"},
    {"values":{"x":454663,"y":154},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"},
    {"values":{"x":455100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"},
    {"values":{"x":456100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"},
    {"values":{"x":457100,"y":0},"key":"rpi/SBS_01"}
]
```

You can use a tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON.

**Edit:** notice too you're also missing a colon between "values" and the next { on your second line.

Comment: The missing colon was a copy and paste mistake, sorry for bad data :).  As for the need to format the values as an array.  My problem is that I don't control the producer of the data at this point and it puts multiple JSON objects into a single file without the square brackets or carriage returns.

Comment: Eek seriously? You should contact the provider and tell them they're spitting out invalid JSON. Short of building your own parser for it, you might very well be out of luck.